# UI5 highlight issue

Tags: ios, sapui5

I am confused with the selection & highlight with UI5 controls on mobile touch devices, such as IPad. As far as I know, sap.m.Text is supported to be highlighted, but for other controls like "sap.ui.core.HTML", it is not.But I just cannot highlight or select them in iPad or Win8 touch devices.
Just to make it clear, what I mean is when you "long press", in other words, "tap hold", the selection frame of Safari, e.g.,will not come out. Is there anything missing ?
Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have some code you've tried so far? If so, post it as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

For controls that don't support the taphold event you can extend them.

You could use jQuery's [taphold](https://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/) event.

So, a pattern like this:

```
onBeforeRendering: function() {
    this.$().off("taphold");
},

onAfterRendering: function() {
    this.$().on("taphold", function(e) {
        // custom behavior
    });
}
```